# How to include a blade which is in public directory, #Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have uploaded blade file which is inside the

> /public/storage/apps/{**MY FILE **}

And now I want to include that in my master view. I have used the normal syntax to achieve this.

```
@include('path')
```

but it doesn't work as it looks for the path of the view directory. I had also tried for'

`@include(url('path')`)

I am fresher and don't know how to address the path from the root directory.

Help will be appreciated.
Thanx.

Comment: I believe in the `config/view.php` config file you are able to provide `View Storage Paths`

Comment: i guess if i changed the default path, all the other path address need to get changed for the whole app

Comment: Refer to my answer below - I believe you are able to provide multiple paths :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open up `config/view.php` file, you should be able to register multiple paths on there:

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | View Storage Paths
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Most templating systems load templates from disk. Here you may specify
    | an array of paths that should be checked for your views. Of course
    | the usual Laravel view path has already been registered for you.
    |
    */

    'paths' => [
        realpath(base_path('resources/views')),
    ],
```